# Mozilla's JavaScript issues

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mozilla, errata

I'm preparing a presentation about JavaScript in different browsers.

I know that there are several issues with Mozilla. For example the constructor of the `Date` object will not accept the ISO date string. It will result in invalid date.

I've been looking for a errata which lists all known issues of this browser in one place. But I couldn't find such.

Q: Does anyone know some link or document that lists the issues of this browser. At least the most significant ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Passing in an ISO date string works fine for me, as shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrdzy/).  Note that it's interpreted as UTC.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I mean this format "2012-02-10T13:19:11+0000"

Comment: That doesn't match the format from the ECMAScript 5 spec.  The prescribed format from §15.9.1.15 is "2012-02-10T13:19:11+00:00" [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrdzy/1/)).  Note the required colon in the timezone offset.  You could also use "Z" instead of "+00:00" since the offset is 0.

Comment: Depends on how exhaustive you want this list to be. All known issues with Mozilla javascript are listed here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?product=Core&component=JavaScript%20Engine

Comment: @thg435, not everything there is an actual bug.  In fact, the [behavior](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682754) the OP discussed is listed there even though it's acknowledged in the report that Firefox complies with ECMAScript's required behavior (ES allows for extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to want is [bug 445494](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=445494) - a tracking bug for all known ECMAScript 5 compliance issues. Look at the open bugs that it depends on. There are apparently two strict mode issues left (disabling `document.all` in strict mode and throwing an exception if a variable is accessed too early), `String.match` and `String.replace` methods don't update `RegExp.lastIndex` property, some non-standard special treatment for the `Array.length` property and a few similarly small issues.